# Apache Camel - Spring DSL - Pass String argument to bean method

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

On Camel 2.10.1, the following worked:

```
<camel:bean ref="profilingBean" method="addProfilingContext('TEST')"/>
```

The method in question takes a String parameter

Migrating to 2.10.6 , this does not work anymore, it tries to call TEST as another class. I have tried wrapping with ${} , trying to use exotic combinations of "& quot;" etc...

The only solution I found was to put the value in a header using constant language then call the header using simple. Obviously, this isn't very clean...

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution with the header is fine. The bug you talk about should be fixed in 2.10.7, or 2.11.1 etc.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior/bug still exists in `Camel 2.16` and also in latest `2.18.2`.

For every string constant that is passed to a bean via Spring DSL a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` is thrown. 
It gets more visible by setting logger for `org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper` to `TRACE`.

This camel behavior also has serious negative performance impact because `ClassLoader` method (`java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass`) is synchronized for a given parameter name.
I wrote a little demo to show this: https://github.com/groundhog2k/camel-dsl-bean-bug