# Apache Camel Java DSL pass class parameter to bean method

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I am using Camel 2.13.1 I want to pass a class as parameter to one of my methods in the bean

Can I do something like

```
In Route
    --
     .beanRef("someSpringBeanRef","someMethod(${body},com.test.TestObject)")
    --

And in Bean
      public Object someMethod(String testBody, Class type){
```

I know I can send the qualified class name in header and use it within the bean but it doesn't feel too right. Are there any other alternatives?

I saw this link but it did not work for me
[Apache Camel - Spring DSL - Pass String argument to bean method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788241/apache-camel-spring-dsl-pass-string-argument-to-bean-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A method parameter of type `Class` is not supported. From the [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html):

Camel uses the following rules to determine if it's a parameter value in the method option

- The value is either true or false which denotes a boolean value
- The value is a numeric value such as 123 or 7
- The value is a String enclosed with either single or double quotes
- The value is null which denotes a null value
- It can be evaluated using the Simple language, which means you can use, e.g., body, header.foo and other Simple tokens. Notice the tokens must be enclosed with ${ }.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the wild card symbol '*'. Camel will try to convert parameter to the correct type.

Route:

```
public class Routes extends RouteBuilder {
     public void configure() throws Exception {
         from("direct:in").bean(new TestBean(), "test(*, ${body})");
     }
}
```

Bean:

```
public class TestBean {
    public void test(Class<?> clazz, String str) {
        System.out.println(clazz);
    }        
}
```

Camel context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ctx.addRoutes(new Routes());
    ctx.start();        
    ctx.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:in", String.class);
    ctx.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:in", "java.lang.String");
}
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
```